# ucthesis + polyglossia hebrew + hyperref = TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: errors, hyperref, titles, polyglossia, hebrew

I've run into an issue with the ucthesis class where using Hebrew language in polyglossia and using hyperref results in a "TeX capacity exceeded" error when using \maketitle (and only then!) I've put in some effort to find what seems to be the minimal code that still produces the error:

```
\documentclass{ucthesis}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Note that this code has been pared down so much it should actually throw a different error, since I haven't defined all of the things ucthesis needs for \maketitle, but I wanted to create the minimal example. It is absolutely required to include the \maketitle line to produce the error; nothing else will create it.

Even more confusingly, if I make a custom local ucthesis.cls and replace the \maketitle definition with:

```
\def\maketitle{a}
```

I can still produce the error.

I have produced this error on both MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows XP and on MacTeX-2012 on Mac OS 10.7 (I'll give MacTeX-2013 a shot soon).

Help?

Comment: `\usepackage{etex}`

Comment: I can produce the same error with:

`\documentclass{ucthesis}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reasons, `\maketitle` gets redefined twice, and the second time `\HyOrg@maketitle` (what `hyperref` uses to store the old meaning of `\maketitle`) points to itself, thus creating a loop.

This seems to happen when the Hebrew language is loaded. The following trick should help. However, it seems a problem with `ucthesis`, because the issue doesn't appear with the standard classes.

```
\documentclass{ucthesis}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\let\keptmaketitle\maketitle

\usepackage{hyperref}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\let\maketitle\keptmaketitle

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```